# MySQL get last two characters and not duplicates

Tags: mysql

I ned to get from mysql database last characters so that i can populate listview elements in android device.

I have this in database:

```
Aaaaa De
Bbbbb De
Ccccc Aut
Ddddd jjjj Slo
Fff fgz kiuj Gb
```

So that i can get from mysql

```
Aut
De
Gb
Slo
```

And don't shot duplicates (in this example duplicates is De)

What it needs to look query?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Maybe you should show your attempt with table name en column names included..

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Try [DISTINCT RIGHT](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-right-function.php)

```
SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(zipcodes, 2) ZIPCODE_2_DIGIT FROM tbl
```